# Is it possible to override an array which had the length of 0 when initialized?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, null, overriding

Im trying to figure out a way to override a specific array in this scenario.
Im iterating through a LinkedList and when I encounter the Element null I am supposed to add the index of the Element to an already defined array of ints.

```
public int [] indexes()       
{
    int [] result = new int [0];
    int counter  = 0;
    Element current = first;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i< size() ; i++)
    {
        if(current.getContent()==null)
        {
            counter++;     
        }
    }

    int [] temp = new int [counter];

    current = first;

    for(int i = 0 ; i< size() ; i++)
    {
        if(current.getContent()==null)
        {
            temp[k++] = i ;

        }
    }

    result = temp;
    return result;
```

As you can already see, I have an array with no elements in it and a length of 0.

Afterwards Im iterating through the List to check if and how many Elements are null. When I find one I increment the counter.

I set up a new temporary array with the length of the counter and the fill the temporary Element with the indexes.

1st Question : Does the line result = temp; work as intended? Does the array called result now contain the array of temp?

2nd Question : How can I check if an Element is null in a LinkedList without getting a NullpointerException? I tried using the following in my if conditions:

1. current == null
2. current.getContent() == null
3. current.equals(null)
4. current.getContent().equals(null)

All of those returned a counter of 0 which means it didnt increment the counter when encountering a Null-Element. How can I rewrite the if conditions?

Comment: 1) There is no array called `result`. There is a *reference* variable named `result`, which can refer to an array. Before `result = temp`, it refers to a zero-sized array. After `result = temp`, it refers to the same array as `temp` does.

Comment: What is `first`?

Comment: First is just the first Element in the LinkedList. To the array thing. There is an array or is there? I mean i declared it at the beginning of the method. Shouldnt it override it?

Comment: What is the point of `current` if you never advance it to the next element? Right now, it's always referring to the first element.

Comment: Okay current.getContent() == null was the way to go. Now the counter actually increments as intended. Also thank you for the tip with actually setting the pointer of current to the next Element. Cant believe I forgot that. Last thing that is still unanswered is how to override the result array?

Comment: You're already doing it.

Comment: ```int [] result = new int [0];``` is not needed or useful.  You never do anything with that zero length array.   And ```result = temp;  return result;```  could be simplified to ```return temp;``` since you never actually do anything significant with ```result```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: Yes. result and temp refer to the same data.

Question 2: your for loop is problematic:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< size() ; i++)
{
    if(current.getContent()==null)
    {
        temp[k++] = i ;

    }
}
```

You're not changing current, so it's always pointed to the first element.

I'm not sure if you're using Java's LinkedList<> or implementing your own.

I wrote this little program. I think it demonstrates what you're trying to do:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();;
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("There");
        list.add(null);

        for (String str: list) {
            System.out.println(str != null ? str : "<null>");
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int index = 0;
        for (String str: list) {
            if (str == null) {
                indexes.add(index);
            }
            ++index;
        }
        for (Integer thisIndex: indexes) {
            System.out.println(thisIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, you would need to convert from ArrayList into an int[]. But the output from this little guy is:

```
$ javac Foo.java && java Foo
Hello
There
<null>
2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to solve the problem very similar to you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to override the result array with this line.

`result = temp;`

Also the way to check if an Element is null in the List was:

```
current.getContent() == null;
```

And last I actually forgot setting the current pointer to the next Element which actually was my biggest problem:

```
current = current.getSucc();
```

Thanks for everyone's help and time. I really appreciate it!